# Data Sharing between two accounts, but with a capability to modify data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need inputs on ways to achieve this scenario

In Data Sharing between two accounts, I understand Consumer can read (SELECT) data provided by Provider.
Is it possible for Consumer to insert/update data into the same table provided by Provider.

Here is the scenario I would like to achieve.

1. Provider shares `TABLE-A` with 3 Columns (`Value1`, `Value2`, `AggValue` columns). Provider inserts data only into `Value1` and `Value2` columns.
2. Consumer performs calculations by reading data from `Value1` and `Value2` columns and updates `AggValue` column in `TABLE-A` provided by Provider
3. Provides now reads data from `AggValue` column that Consumer has updated

Note: It is single table `Table-A` that both Provider and Consumer are acting on.

Is above scenario possible to implement using Data Sharing, if not what are the suggested alternatives.

Thanks & Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this can't be done directly in a single data share, but can be completed leveraging 2 data shares...1 in each direction.

In your scenario `Provider A` shares a table with the `value1` and `value2` to `Consumer B`.  `Consumer B` then uses that data to populate a table in another database with `value1`, `value2`, and `AggValue`.  Then, `Consumer B` shares that database back to `Provider A`.

Shares are single-direction, but a share can be created on each account going to the other account.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Walton for confirming that two accounts cannot act on single table using Data Share. If I may extend my question for the same scenario, is same valid for Data Exchange and Data Marketplace (DMP) as well.  The rationale behind my question is, I was watching recent Snowflake Data Cloud Summit demo on Data Marketplace (DMP) and the demo was referring to an listing (Financial Crimes Risk Assessment) by `Quantified Inc`. The usage example in that data marketplace listing seems to refer to a single table and both parties acting on the same table. Wondering if this scenario is possible?

Comment: Data Exchange and Data Marketplace are simply a way to list data shares and subscribe to them from a single portal.  The end result is still a 1-way share to a consumer.  Not sure which demo in particular you were viewing, but a data share is always read-only to a consumer.